# How to create SQL Server stored procedure returning an array?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Sorry for this maybe foolish question but i'm newbie to SQL Server. Here structure of my table of divisions at organization:

```
id int(16) -- simply unique id
sub_id int(16) -- this id of parent division in this table (if zero, than it don't have parent)
name VARCHAR(200) -- name of division
```

I need to create a simply procedure which return me all id of subdivisions in some division (with top division id too). I think i need array with subid's in loop, but i don't know how to create array in SQL Serve o_0 (omg.. array exist in (T)SQL language ? =). Help please. Or maybe another way to get it?

Comment: @abatishchev omg, you edited his question. kthxbye

Comment: @alex: Do you think i shouldn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly you need a recursive CTE.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo
@id int
AS

WITH divisions AS
(
SELECT id, sub_id, name
FROM YourTable
WHERE id = @id
UNION ALL
SELECT y.id, y.sub_id, y.name
FROM YourTable y
JOIN divisions d ON d.id = y.sub_id
)

SELECT id, sub_id, name
FROM divisions
```

Comment: you have a little mistake - "JOIN divisions d ON d.id = y.sub_id" change this and i will mark your answer as accepted =)

Comment: @0dd_b1t - Ah I often mess that up when I haven't got the data to test against! Done.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE sub_id = @target
UNION ALL
SELECT @target
```

Comment: @0dd_b1t: Seems that @Martin's answer is what you're looking for